# how to add AdWords Conversion Tracking code to a specific form in drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal, google-ads-api

I am an  newbie in Drupal, I have this javascript code to insert in a form on my website to add Google AdWords Conversion Tracking  to the contact page.I cannot find the way to do it. Can someone help me.

```
<!-- Google Code for Formulaire en ligne Conversion Page --> <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 00000000000;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""  
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/00000000000/?label=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

I've already use module Google AdWords Conversion Tracking but it doesn't work and don't know what I do wrong. So I want to add this code javascript but I don't how to do add a javascript code to a specific page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Admin we can create one node and post the java-script code inside the page editor.

Comment: share the link or screenshot for clarity